# How do you change the foreground color of a stackpanel in xaml

Tags: xaml

I have this in my App.xaml

```
 <Style x:Key="ColorBlack" TargetType="StackPanel">
      <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
 </Style>
```

And this on a xaml page

```
 <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ColorBlack}"></StackPanel>
```

In the designer the color changes to black but when i run the application on a device it crashes and says it doesn't know the name ColorBlack.

Comment: I could be wrong, but a StackPanel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel(v=vs.110).aspx doesn't have a foreground property ... it is an element for holding other UI components, not have a visual presence itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />

    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock"/>
    <Label Content="Label"/>
    <Button Content="Button"/>
    <TextBox Text="TextBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: For implicit styles to apply to an element, the TargetType must match exactly. It won't work with a base class like FrameworkElement.